# How do I expose the DayOfWeek enum in my interface?

Tags: c#, enums, interface, com, dayofweek

In my COM DLL I want to include a DayOfWeek property:

```
private DayOfWeek _MeetingDay;
```

When I will my wrapper in C++ and examine the interface:

```
 virtual HRESULT __stdcall get_MeetingDay (
   /*[out,retval]*/ enum DayOfWeek * pRetVal ) = 0;
 virtual HRESULT __stdcall put_MeetingDay (
   /*[in]*/ enum DayOfWeek pRetVal ) = 0;
```

My problem is the the enum does not seem to be defined:

```
MSAToolsLibrary::DayOfWeek eMeetingDay = MSAToolsLibrary::DayOfWeek_Sunday;
```

But, if I start typing like this:

[image]

They are listed. Yet I can't even use that approach. How do I expose the `DayOfWeek` enum?

---

I know how to expose my own enums:

```
[Guid("xxx")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public enum NotesModeCLM
{
    EmailAddress,
    PhoneNumber,
    Remarks
}
```

But not C# enums.

Comment: Answer depend if the input is a string or a number.  Try one of following : DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), "0");

            DayOfWeek day0 = (DayOfWeek)(0);

Comment: You can't multiply an Enum by a integer without a cast : (int)(enum DayOfWeek) * pRetVal

Comment: It is c++ pointer.  You just need to pass an integer 0 to 6 and c++ will cast the number to a DayOFWeek.  So  if you have a DayOfWeek just add a cast (int)DayOfWeek in c#.

Comment: It's not fully clear what you're doing. Is your COM Server C++ or C#? Is your COM client C++ or C#? Are you talking about exposing .NET DayOfWeek (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek) from a C++ Server? Or is it your own DayOfWeek definition?

Comment: @SimonMourier c# is the dll / interface. The E-number is dot net enum. C++ is using that dll

Comment: You still don't answer my questions. Shot in the dark: if you want to use .NET Framework DayOfWeek exposed in a .NET COM object, from a C++ client, then you need to add a `#import "mscorlib.tlb" auto_rename` somewhere. Then you'll be able to use `mscorlib::DayOfWeek_Friday` for example.

Comment: @SimonMourier You completely understood. I was not familiar with the right terms to use. So thank you.

Comment: @jdweng We can delete all our comments.